# What is /boot/firmware? What is it used for?

Tags: boot, 20.04, broadcom, raspberrypi

This is my partition layout on Raspberry Pi 4 (Ubuntu 20.04 LTS image)

```
root@jk4:/home/ubuntu# lsblk
NAME        MAJ:MIN RM  SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
sda           8:0    0  3.7T  0 disk
└─sda1        8:1    0  3.7T  0 part
mmcblk0     179:0    0 29.1G  0 disk
├─mmcblk0p1 179:1    0  256M  0 part /boot/firmware
└─mmcblk0p2 179:2    0 28.9G  0 part /
```

I wonder what `/boot/firmware` is? Is it Raspberry specific?

In Wikipedia I found only [`/boot`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki//boot/), this is also what I learned from books many years ago.

```
root@jk4:/home/ubuntu# ls -al /boot/firmware
total 99020
drwxr-xr-x 3 root root     4096 Jan  1  1970 .
drwxr-xr-x 4 root root     4096 Jul  4 05:29 ..
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root    26247 Jul  4 05:29 bcm2710-rpi-2-b.dtb
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root    26247 Jul  4 05:28 bcm2710-rpi-2-b.dtb.bak
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root    27288 Jul  4 05:29 bcm2710-rpi-3-b.dtb
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root    27288 Jul  4 05:28 bcm2710-rpi-3-b.dtb.bak
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root    27907 Jul  4 05:29 bcm2710-rpi-3-b-plus.dtb
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root    27907 Jul  4 05:28 bcm2710-rpi-3-b-plus.dtb.bak
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root    26102 Jul  4 05:29 bcm2710-rpi-cm3.dtb
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root    26102 Jul  4 05:28 bcm2710-rpi-cm3.dtb.bak
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root    46368 Jul  4 05:29 bcm2711-rpi-4-b.dtb
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root    46368 Jul  4 05:28 bcm2711-rpi-4-b.dtb.bak
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root    19924 Jul  4 05:29 bcm2837-rpi-3-a-plus.dtb
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root    19924 Jul  4 05:28 bcm2837-rpi-3-a-plus.dtb.bak
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root    20373 Jul  4 05:29 bcm2837-rpi-3-b.dtb
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root    20373 Jul  4 05:28 bcm2837-rpi-3-b.dtb.bak
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root    20793 Jul  4 05:29 bcm2837-rpi-3-b-plus.dtb
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root    20793 Jul  4 05:28 bcm2837-rpi-3-b-plus.dtb.bak
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root    19700 Jul  4 05:29 bcm2837-rpi-cm3-io3.dtb
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root    19700 Jul  4 05:28 bcm2837-rpi-cm3-io3.dtb.bak
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root    52304 Apr 23 15:12 bootcode.bin
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root     2603 Jul  4 05:29 boot.scr
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root     2603 Jul  4 05:28 boot.scr.bak
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root      141 Apr 23 15:12 cmdline.txt
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root     1117 Apr 23 15:12 config.txt
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root     3112 Apr 23 15:12 fixup4cd.dat
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root     6200 Apr 23 15:12 fixup4.dat
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root     9192 Apr 23 15:12 fixup4db.dat
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root     9192 Apr 23 15:12 fixup4x.dat
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root     2656 Apr 23 15:12 fixup_cd.dat
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root     6745 Apr 23 15:12 fixup.dat
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root     9817 Apr 23 15:12 fixup_db.dat
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root     9819 Apr 23 15:12 fixup_x.dat
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 29527996 Jul  4 05:29 initrd.img
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 29528551 Jul  4 05:28 initrd.img.bak
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root      240 Apr 23 15:12 meta-data
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root      770 Apr 23 15:12 network-config
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root     1371 Jul  4 05:29 overlay_map.dtb
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root     1371 Jul  4 05:28 overlay_map.dtb.bak
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root    34816 Jul  4 05:29 overlays
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root     1514 Apr 23 15:12 README
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root   784316 Apr 23 15:12 start4cd.elf
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root  4593508 Apr 23 15:12 start4db.elf
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root  2784800 Apr 23 15:12 start4.elf
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root  3546468 Apr 23 15:12 start4x.elf
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root   690884 Apr 23 15:12 start_cd.elf
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root  4859912 Apr 23 15:12 start_db.elf
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root  2883204 Apr 23 15:12 start.elf
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root  3797384 Apr 23 15:12 start_x.elf
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root      327 Apr 23 15:12 syscfg.txt
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root   493528 Apr 23 15:12 uboot_rpi_3.bin
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root   492824 Apr 23 15:12 uboot_rpi_4.bin
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root      200 Apr 23 15:12 usercfg.txt
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root     2114 Apr 23 15:12 user-data
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root  8381742 Jul  4 05:29 vmlinuz
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root  8381742 Jul  4 05:28 vmlinuz.bak
```

I recognize a few files like the Linux Kernel. The `bcm*` looks like Broadcom stuff. Please provide details about it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Is it Raspberry specific?

Yes. Sort of. The files to me are more important and are indeed for a PI installation. `/boot/firmware` is not a default Linux directory.

Regarding the content: see [raspberrypi](https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/configuration/boot_folder.md)'s topic on "boot":

> **start.elf, start_x.elf, start_db.elf, start_cd.elf, start4.elf, start4x.elf, start4cd.elf, start4db.elf**
>
> These are binary blobs (firmware) that are loaded on to the VideoCore in the SoC, which then take over the boot process. start.elf is the basic firmware, `start_x.elf` includes camera drivers and codec, start_db.elf is a debug version of the firmware, and `start_cd.elf` is a cut-down version with no support hardware blocks like codecs and 3D, and for use when `gpu_mem=16` is specified in config.txt. More information on how to use these can be found in the config.txt section.
>
> start4.elf, start4x.elf, start4cd.elf, and start4db.elf are firmware files specific to the Pi 4.

Some other files are listed too.